# Having a method run at application start continuously

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jpa, push-notification

I am having a little bit of trouble with something I am trying to pull off. I have an application that uses Java 19 and Springboot that is being hosted locally (but will eventually be hosted elsewhere). I have an SQL database setup on the same. I want to be able to send users an email, based on the due date of an event they are participating in. I have a few methods that allow me to query using JPA to find these emails, the issue I am having is actually calling these methods. I want these methods to run on intervals of 5 minutes always (that is to say, I want the methods to query the DB every 5 minutes of so). Is there a way to do this? As of now any call to a repository is triggered by events on the front-end, and I am uncertain as to how I could call these methods continuously? Please find below the methods:

```
mport java.util.Timer;

//Main class
public class SchedulerMain {
    
    
    
    
    //Timer for 7 days
    public static Boolean sevenDays() throws InterruptedException {

        Timer time = new Timer(); // Instantiate Timer Object
        ScheduledTaskSevenDays st = new ScheduledTaskSevenDays(); // Instantiate SheduledTask class
        time.schedule(st, 0, 300000); // Create Repetitively task for every 5 minutes
        
        return true;
    
    }
}


public class ScheduledTaskSevenDays extends TimerTask {


    @Autowired
    private AdminService adminService;

    // To run for 7 days
    public void run() {
        //Going to call on method here to gather participants and send email
        adminService.SevenDayNotification();
    }
}

 public boolean SevenDayNotification() { 
        System.out.println("Start of email Method");
         try {
             
             
             //Get Survey Participation from DB
             List<String> surveyParticipation;
             surveyParticipation = surveyParticipationRepository.findAllParticipantEmailSevenDays();
             System.out.println("we have a list of participants");
 
             //send emails to all participants in the survey
             for(int i = 0; i<surveyParticipation.size(); i++)
             {
                 System.out.println("im in the loop");
                 emailService.sendMessage(surveyParticipation.get(i), "Notice: Survey will end soon", "This survey is set to end in 7 days, please be sure to complete and submit it before the due date." );
             }
             System.out.println("we are returning true");
             //return true if successful
             return true;
            
         }
         catch(Exception e){
             //return false if unsuccessful
             System.out.println("I have failed at sending email");
             System.out.println(e.getMessage());
             return false;
         }
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@Scheduled` annotation.

In your main application class, you need to first enable scheduling.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class MyApplication {
    // ...
}
```

Then, add `@Scheduled` to a method of one of your components.

```java
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
@Component 
public class MyTask {
    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
    public void run() {
        // execute periodic task
    }
}
```

Comment: TYSM this was exactly the missing piece I was looking for!